# laravel 4 validator error array to string conversion

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

Hi guys I have a validator error that i can't find a solution.
I have the following validation rules:

```
'meta_description'     => 'required|max:200',
'meta_keywords'        => 'required|max:200',
'item_url'             => 'required|max:500',
'categories'           => 'required|not_in:0',
'tags'                 => 'required|not_in:0',
'title'                => 'required|max:150',
'description'          => 'required|max:500',
'author-name'          => 'required|max:250',
'author-link'          => 'required|max:250',
'format'               => 'required|max:300',
'smart-objects'        => 'required|max:300',
'dimensions'           => 'required|max:300',
'photoshop-version'    => 'required|max:300',
'file-size'            => 'max:300',
'link'                 => 'max:500',
'main_item_image'      =>'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:10000',
'item_image'           => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|max:10000',
```

Validation works but when all inputs are filled and i try to submit i get the following error: Array to string conversion","file":"\path to laravel project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php","line":858.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem tags validation contains multiples id and not_in:0 was the problem.

Comment: What do you mean multiple id ? cause i got an error too

Comment: I meant tags is a select so there is a list of options each one with unique id.